# How to get an array[$i] call name and whats in it

Tags: php, arrays

I need to find out whats in the first [] to place it into mysql since it equals the Primary key.

then I can also get whats in it.

I was thinking about Array[$i]

Any ideas?

```
Array
(
    [] => 16
    [5273] => 54
    [5298] => 81
    [5357] => 42
    [5317] => 116
    [5331] => 8
    [5402] => 72
    [5289] => 45
    [5332] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key=$value, "; // this will output 5273=54, 5298=81, ...
}
```

Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//$array contains your array
reset($array);
echo current($array);
```

This should return the first element of your array.

Alternatively, you could use $array[0] to reference the first element of the array.